# extract variables in formula from a data frame

Tags: r, r-formula

I have a formula that contains some terms and a data frame (the output of an earlier `model.frame()` call) that contains all of those terms and some more.  I want the subset of the model frame that contains only the variables that appear in the formula.

```
ff <- log(Reaction) ~ log(1+Days) + x + y
fr <- data.frame(`log(Reaction)`=1:4,
                 `log(1+Days)`=1:4,
                 x=1:4,
                 y=1:4,
                 z=1:4,
                 check.names=FALSE)
```

The desired result is `fr` minus the `z` column (`fr[,1:4]` is cheating -- I need a programmatic solution ...)

Some strategies that *don't* work:

```
fr[all.vars(ff)]
## Error in `[.data.frame`(fr, all.vars(ff)) : undefined columns selected
```

(because `all.vars()` gets `"Reaction"`, not `log("Reaction")`)

```
stripwhite <- function(x) gsub("(^ +| +$)","",x)
vars <- stripwhite(unlist(strsplit(as.character(ff)[-1],"\\+")))
fr[vars]
## Error in `[.data.frame`(fr, vars) : undefined columns selected
```

(because splitting on `+` spuriously splits the `log(1+Days)` term).

I've been thinking about walking down the parse tree of the formula:

```
ff[[3]]       ## log(1 + Days) + x + y
ff[[3]][[1]]  ## `+`
ff[[3]][[2]]  ## log(1 + Days) + x
```

but I haven't got a solution put together, and it seems like I'm going down a rabbit hole.  Ideas?

Comment: Seems like the main variable that's causing you problems is `log(1+Days)`. Do you have to call it that or could you just use a different name?

Comment: What about `attr(terms.formula(ff), "term.labels")`?

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a general solution.  Therefore, anything that could show up in a `model.frame()` generated from a legal formula has to be handled.  That's part of the problem.

Comment: Or `rownames(attr(terms.formula(ff), "factors"))` to get the DV as well.

Comment: Very nice. Do you guys know this magic by heart or did you just browse through `str(ff)` looking for something that would help?

Comment: `?formula` lists `terms.formula`. :)

Comment: And now I know that "háček" is officially called a "caron" in English -- I was looking for the compose-key sequence for š (it's Compose-c-s) so I could reference Roman (and Thomas) in my code

Comment: Can you guarantee that any variable (or function turned into a variable as in your example) will exist in `fr` ?  It sort of seems suspicious to me that you're creating the `ff` manually but it always works out that `fr` "covers" the variable list.  What I'm leading up to is that it looks like you've previously created a bunch of variable names and functions, so there may be a simpler way to save those as character strings, and then load these char strings  into an `as.formula` or similar call when creating `ff` .

Comment: the slightly larger context is that `fr` was generated from a formula; that formula was then manipulated (some terms dropped), and I want to extract the portion of the model frame that corresponds to the non-dropped terms. I'm reasonably happy with the answer I got here, which is magical but fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
> fr[gsub(" ","",rownames(attr(terms.formula(ff), "factors")))]
  log(Reaction) log(1+Days) x y
1             1           1 1 1
2             2           2 2 2
3             3           3 3 3
4             4           4 4 4
```

And props to Roman Luštrik for pointing me in the right direction.

Edit: Looks like you could pull it out off the "variables" attribute as well:

```
fr[gsub(" ","",attr(terms(ff),"variables")[-1])]
```

Edit 2: Found first problem case, involving `I()` or `offset()`:

```
ff <- I(log(Reaction)) ~ I(log(1+Days)) + x + y
fr[gsub(" ","",attr(terms(ff),"variables")[-1])]
```

Those would be pretty easy to correct with regex, though. BUT, if you had situations like in the question where a variable is called, e.g., `log(x)` and is used in a formula alongside something like `I(log(y))` for variable `y`, this will get really messy.

Comment: thanks.  I can't accept this for another few minutes.  the `gsub(...)` won't be necessary in my case, I think -- the mismatch in white space won't be there.  I introduced it accidentally in setting up the example.

Comment: @BenBolker Yea, it would probably be good to test this on some other formula constructions to see if it's general...

Comment: but your original answer, `rownames(attr(terms.formula(ff), "factors")))`, seems to work fine on your problem case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the only problem is the lack of a space in the name of the second column of fr.  Rename it with a space and pull the columns in this way:

```
ff <- log(Reaction) ~ log(1+Days) + x + y
fr <- data.frame(`log(Reaction)`=1:4,
                 `log(1 + Days)`=1:4,
                 x=1:4,
                 y=1:4,
                 z=1:4,
                 check.names=FALSE)


fr[labels(terms(ff))]
```

If you believe the only difference between the two will always be that the names of `fr` has spaces where the names in `ff` don't, then the above solution holds.  I like `labels(terms(x))` a bit more, though, because it seems a bit more abstract.

```
fr[gsub(pattern = ' ', replacement = '', x = labels(terms(ff)))]
```